# Failed uninstallation, still listed in Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1, extensions, magento-connect

I experienced some errors during uninstallation of an extension.
The files of the extensions are deleted, but the extension is still listed in Magento Connect Manager.

1. Why?
2. How can I properly uninstall?

Comment: How you install  & Uninstall??

Comment: through Magento Connect Manager

Comment: check all file's are deleted or not clear your cache and session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving full permission to downloader folder and deleting the file which was mentioned in the error message as not existing, uninstallation worked.